# Can I have two DHCP servers for IPv4/IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, dhcp-server, ipv4

I have an IPv6 block, However the network is based on an IPv4 only router. I can't change that router for several reasons.

Can I have a DHCPv6 server with DHCPv4 server? Or do I have to disable DHCPv4 from the IPv4 router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are independent, and the DHCPv6 server should also respond to v6 requests only.

If you use server software that supports both, you may need to explicitly disable responses to v4 requests, and you may run into issues if your DHCP server also updates local DNS (e.g. because an update flushes all records and then only adds records for one address family).

Also, the DNS settings handed out by both servers should be consistent.

If you don't need any features beyond address assignment, stateless autoconfiguration through router advertisements may be sufficient for you.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thanks for helping me.